# How to return value using IJavaScriptExecutor execute script function when a long java script code is entered in it

Tags: c#, selenium

```
string selectedManagerValue = getElement_RuntimeText(drv, By.XPath("//*[@id='auditManager']/option[@selected='selected']"));
string script = @"var d = document.querySelectorAll('#abcManager/deep/option') ;
     for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
        if ( d[i].innerText == 'arguments[0]' || d[i].innerText == 'Select')
            continue;
        else
          {d[i].innerText;
            break;}
            };";

 string newManagerValue = (string)js.ExecuteScript(" return "+script, selectedManagerValue);
```

**This is my code when i run it it gives me the below error :**

****expected expression, got keyword 'var' (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)****

```
UnpackAndThrowOnError(OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.Response)}
-(string)js.ExecuteScript(" return "+script, selectedManagerValue)  '(string)js.ExecuteScript(" return "+script, selectedManagerValue)' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

The javascript works perfectly fine when i execute it in the chrome console.Not sure what exactly I am missing here.

Comment: Your script doesn't have anything to return and the argument you provided is not used. What is the script supposed to do?

Comment: I am trying to return the dropdown value other than the selectedManagerValue ...i am expecting the output of this d[i].innerText; to be returned